# Cannot align to center

Tags: java, swing

I can't get theTimer to align to the center of the screen, I don't understand what is going on
I've tried every Layout format I know and cannot get it to work
The timer is in the center of the screen if it is the only thing on the panel and I use FlowLayout, but I cannot simply add the button because I want it to be beneath the timer.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestBomb extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int WIDTH = 1000;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
private String armPassword,disarmPassword;
private Timer timer = null;
private int heldTime=0;
private int mins;
private Timer hold=null;
private int secs;
private JPanel timerSpot=null;
private int totalSeconds;
private Container content=null;
private JTextField type;
private JTextField theTimer;
private JButton defuse=null;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public TestBomb() {
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    addWindowListener(new WindowDestroyer());
    content = this.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.black);
    type = new JTextField(25);
    type.setActionCommand("Enter");
    type.setForeground(Color.green);
    type.setBackground(Color.black);
    type.addActionListener(this);
    armPassword = null;//Method implemented later
    disarmPassword=null;//Method implemented later
    JPanel passwordPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel passwordSpot = new JLabel("Arm Password: "+armPassword);
    passwordSpot.setForeground(Color.white);
    passwordSpot.setSize(50, 30);
    JLabel disarmPasswordSpot = new JLabel("Disarm Password: "+disarmPassword);
    disarmPasswordSpot.setForeground(Color.white);
    disarmPasswordSpot.setSize(50, 30);
    passwordPanel.add(passwordSpot);
    passwordPanel.add(type);
    passwordPanel.add(disarmPasswordSpot);
    passwordPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 51, 0));
    defuse=new JButton("Hold to Defuse");
    defuse.addActionListener(this);
    defuse.setVisible(true);
    defuse.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    content.add(passwordPanel, "South");
    theTimer = new JTextField();
    theTimer.setText("00" + ":" + "00");
    theTimer.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 235));
    theTimer.setBackground(Color.black);
    theTimer.setForeground(Color.green);
    theTimer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    theTimer.setEditable(true);
    theTimer.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    timerSpot = new JPanel();
    timerSpot.setLayout(new BoxLayout(timerSpot,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    timerSpot.setBackground(Color.black);
    timerSpot.add(theTimer);
    timerSpot.add(defuse);
    content.add(timerSpot, "Center");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestBomb timer = new TestBomb();
    timer.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

### Below is the class used to close the window

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

class WindowDestroyer extends WindowAdapter 
{
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
     {
               System.exit(0); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: alright this creates the same problem

Comment: Why is `java.io.FileInputStream` necessary to recreate the problem, and if so, why did you not include a sample input data for the `File`?  2nd the call of @camickr for an *actual* MCVE.

Comment: I've simplified my code to MCVE format

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue, I instead used `FlowLayout()` and added `Box.createHorizontalGlue(1000)` to the code

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem, but you have to use proper [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Just create another JPanel as a main panel which will be added to the contentPane like:

```
JPanel timer=new JPanel();
```

Then add jTextField and JButton to timerSpot panel

```
timerSpot.add(theTimer);
timerSpot.add(defuse);
```

Then add timerSpot panel to timer panel like:

```
timer.add(timerSpot);
```

Now add the timer panel to the contentPane this will position your component to center

```
content.add(timer, "Center");
```